# display of data under several conditions, some of which may not exist

Tags: vue.js

I have an API project where I need to display some data in a table, but I also have two date fields that the user should be able to fill with a start and a last date, and then when the submit button is clicked, only the data where its "date" field is comprised between the two dates is displayed, but i can't find a way to do it.

Here is the part of the code that is concerned :

```
          <input
        style="position: relative; left: 750px"
        type="date"
        label="starting date"
      />
      <input
        style="position: relative; left: 750px"
        type="date"
        label="last date"
      />
      <button
        style="position: relative; left: 750px"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-secondary"
      >
        submit dates
      </button>
      <hr />
      <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        <!--Table Head-->
        <thead class="thead-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">ID</th>
            <th scope="col">apkMode</th>
            <th scope="col">date</th>
            <th scope="col">timestamp</th>
            <th scope="col">user</th>
            <th scope="col">news</th>
            <th scope="col">selfEvaluationQuestion</th>
            <th scope="col">selfEvaluationAnswer</th>
            <th scope="col">questionQuiz</th>
            <th scope="col">answerQuiz</th>
            <th scope="col">quizAnswer</th>
            <th scope="col">questionQ2</th>
            <th scope="col">answerQ2</th>
            <th scope="col">similarityq2</th>
            <th scope="col">questionQ0</th>
            <th scope="col">answerQ0</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(sessions, _id) in sessions" :key="_id">
            <td>{{ sessions._id }}</td>
            <td>{{ sessions.apkMode }}</td>
            <td>{{ sessions.date }}</td>
            <td>{{ sessions.timestamp }}</td>
            <td>{{ sessions.user }}</td>
            <td>
              <span
                v-for="(interactions, index) in sessions.interactions"
                :key="index"
              >
                <p v-if="sessions.interactions[index].type === 'newsCore'">
                  {{ sessions.interactions[index].text }}
                </p>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span
                v-for="(interactions, index) in sessions.interactions"
                :key="index"
              >
                <p
                  v-if="
                    sessions.interactions[index].type ===
                    'selfEvaluationQuestion'
                  "
                >
                  {{ sessions.interactions[index].text }}
                </p>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span
                v-for="(interactions, index) in sessions.interactions"
                :key="index"
              >
                <p
                  v-if="
                    sessions.interactions[index].type ===
                    'selfEvaluationAnswer'
                  "
                >
                  {{ sessions.interactions[index].text }}
                </p>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span
                v-for="(interactions, index) in sessions.interactions"
                :key="index"
              >
                <p
                  v-if="
                    sessions.interactions[index].type === 'questionQuiz'
                  "
                >
                  {{ sessions.interactions[index].text }}
                </p>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span
                v-for="(interactions, index) in sessions.interactions"
                :key="index"
              >
                <p
                  v-if="sessions.interactions[index].type === 'answerQuiz'"
                >
                  {{ sessions.interactions[index].text }}
                </p>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span
                v-for="(interactions, index) in sessions.interactions"
                :key="index"
              >
                <p
                  v-if="sessions.interactions[index].type === 'answerQuiz'"
                >
                  {{ sessions.interactions[index].quizAnswer }}
                </p>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span
                v-for="(interactions, index) in sessions.interactions"
                :key="index"
              >
                <p
                  v-if="sessions.interactions[index].type === 'questionQ2'"
                >
                  {{ sessions.interactions[index].text }}
                </p>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span
                v-for="(interactions, index) in sessions.interactions"
                :key="index"
              >
                <p v-if="sessions.interactions[index].type === 'answerQ2'">
                  {{ sessions.interactions[index].text }}
                </p>
              </span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span
                v-for="(interactions, index) in sessions.interactions"
                :key="index"
              >
                <p v-if="sessions.interactions[index].type === 'answerQ2'">
                  {{ sessions.interactions[index].similarity }}
                </p>
              </span>
            </td>
                            <td>
              <span
                v-for="(interactions, index) in sessions.interactions"
                :key="index"
              >
                <p v-if="sessions.interactions[index].type === 'answerQ0'">
                  {{ sessions.interactions[index].text }}
                </p>
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the javascript part :

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import papa from "papaparse";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
  sessions: [],
};
  },
  methods: {
    getSessions() {
        const path = "http://localhost:5000/data_for_front";
  axios
    .get(path)
    .then((res) => {
      this.sessions = res.data;
      papa.parse(this.sessions, {
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true,
        skipEmptyLines: true,
        complete(result) {
          this.sessions = result.data;
        },
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });
},
```

finally, a sample of the data I am working with :

```
{ 
"_id" : "userid", 
"apkMode" : "SCROLL", 
"date" : "2022-04-25", 
"timestamp" : NumberLong(1650913068512), 
"user" : "username", 
"interactions" : [
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650912989260), 
        "subject" : "ROBOT", 
        "type" : "selfEvaluationQuestion", 
        "text" : "questiontext"
    }, 
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650913013738), 
        "subject" : "HUMAN", 
        "type" : "selfEvaluationAnswer", 
        "text" : "questionresponse"
    }, 
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650913022948), 
        "subject" : "ROBOT", 
        "type" : "newsCore", 
        "text" : "newstext"
    }, 
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650913042076), 
        "subject" : "ROBOT", 
        "type" : "questionQ2", 
        "text" : "Q2text"
    }, 
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650913047978), 
        "subject" : "ROBOT", 
        "type" : "questionQ0", 
        "text" : "Q0text"
    }, 
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650913047978), 
        "subject" : "HUMAN", 
        "type" : "answerQ2", 
        "text" : "Q2answer", 
        "similarity" : 0.0, 
        "correctAnswer" : "Q2correctanswer"
    }, 
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650913058686), 
        "subject" : "HUMAN", 
        "type" : "answerQ0", 
        "text" : "Q0answer"
    }, 
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650913058867), 
        "subject" : "ROBOT", 
        "type" : "questionEnd", 
        "text" : "Endquestion"
    }, 
    {
        "interactionTimestamp" : NumberLong(1650913068512), 
        "subject" : "HUMAN", 
        "type" : "answerEnd", 
        "text" : "Endanswer"
    }
]
}
```

Also, I know I should not be using v-for with v-if but Since my data sample is limited, I have been authorized to for simplicity reasons.

Thanks !